# Unique combinations of two property values

Tags: gremlin

For a given vertex, I'm trying to get the number of unique combinations of two edge properties, but I'm not sure where to begin.

For example, let's say the vertex `147672` has edges which all have properties `P1`, and `P2`.

Those edges might have the following property values: `[(A, B), (B, A), (B, A), (A, C), (C, A), (C,A)']`.

Then the unique combinations of `P1` and `P2`'s values would be `[(A, B), (B, A), (A, C), (C, A)']`, and the length would be four.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are looking to do something along the lines of:

`values('P1','P2').dedup().count()` ? Given these are edge properties the values must be scalar values so I was not exactly sure how to read your groupings like `(A,B)`

Comment: Hi Kevin. Sorry I should have clarified; let's say `P1`, an edge property, has the values - which are strings - `('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C')`, and `P2`, also an edge property, has the values `('B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'A')`. I'm looking to get the number of unique pairs for the values of `P1` *and* `P2` =4, not simply the number of unique values of both=3.

Comment: Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I built a graph that I hope represents what you described above and and also a query to find the pairs.

```
g.addV('V1').as('a').
  addV('V2').as('b').
  addE('edge').from('a').to('b').property('p1','A').property('p2','B').
  addE('edge').from('a').to('b').property('p1','A').property('p2','B').
  addE('edge').from('a').to('b').property('p1','A').property('p2','C').
  addE('edge').from('a').to('b').property('p1','C').property('p2','A').
  addE('edge').from('a').to('b').property('p1','C').property('p2','B').
  iterate()
```

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V1').outE()
==>e[2][0-edge->1]
==>e[3][0-edge->1]
==>e[4][0-edge->1]
==>e[5][0-edge->1]
==>e[6][0-edge->1]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V1').outE().local(values('p1','p2').fold())
==>[A,B]
==>[A,B]
==>[A,C]
==>[C,A]
==>[C,B]

gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('V1').outE().local(values('p1','p2').fold()).dedup()
==>[A,B]
==>[A,C]
==>[C,A]
==>[C,B]
```